# Sum specific rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe which looks similar to this:

```
   ID      Date       EoM_Val    Val
---------------------------------------
  AAA   2021-06-30    100         3
  CCC   2021-06-30    200         2
  BBB   2021-06-30    50          6
  DDD   2021-06-30    10          7
  AAA   2021-07-31    40          6
  CCC   2021-07-31    100         2
  ...    ....         ...        ...
```

And basically, what I would like to do is combine the `AAA` and `CCC` rows together to make `XXX` and also sum their `EoM_Val` and `Val` values together to get the following dataframe:

```
   ID      Date       EoM_Val    Val
---------------------------------------
  XXX   2021-06-30    300         5
  BBB   2021-06-30    50          6
  DDD   2021-06-30    10          7
  XXX   2021-07-31    140         8
  ...    ....         ...        ...
```

I've tried checking around online but I'm finding it difficult to find something relevant to my question, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that id `CCC` is subsequent to id `AAA`, relying on [shifted](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) records (adjacent records are summed up):

```
df['ID'].replace({'CCC': 'XXX'}, inplace=True)
df[['EoM_Val', 'Val']] = np.where(df['ID'].eq('XXX'), [df['EoM_Val'] + df['EoM_Val'].shift(),
                                                       df['Val'] + df['Val'].shift()],
                                  [df['EoM_Val'], df['Val']]).T
df = df[~df['ID'].eq('AAA')]
```

---

```
    ID        Date  EoM_Val  Val
1  XXX  2021-06-30    300.0  5.0
2  BBB  2021-06-30     50.0  6.0
3  DDD  2021-06-30     10.0  7.0
5  XXX  2021-07-31    140.0  8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.assign(ID1 = lambda y : ["XXX" for x in y.ID if x == 'AAA' or x == 'CCC' else x]).group by(["ID1", "Date"])["EoM_Val","Val"].sum().reset_index()
```

First, we will create a second ID using lambda expression and then aggregating them by sum with group by object.

Comment: Consider explaining your solution

Comment: You code has a syntax error (in the comprehension) and a typo `group by`. Try `df.assign(ID=df["ID"].replace({"AAA": "XXX", "CCC": "XXX"})).groupby(["ID", "Date"], as_index=False, sort=False).sum()` instead.

Comment: Your code is good...

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [['AAA', '2021-06-30', 100, 3], ['CCC', '2021-06-30', 200, 2],['BBB', '2021-06-30', 50, 6], ['DDD', '2021-06-30', 10, 7], ['AAA', '2021-07-31', 40, 6], ['CCC', '2021-07-31', 100, 2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID', 'Date', 'EoM_Val', 'Val'])

valuesID = ['AAA', 'CCC']
df2 = df[df['ID'].isin(valuesID)]
df2['ID'] = 'XXX'
df2 = df2.groupby(['ID', 'Date'], as_index=False)[['EoM_Val', 'Val']].sum()
df = df.drop(df[df.ID == 'AAA'].index)
df = df.drop(df[df.ID == 'CCC'].index)
df_final = pd.concat([df, df2], ignore_index=True)
df_final
```

This should work =)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).